# Non-exhaustive patterns in Haskell function that outputs a list of tuples

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am trying to teach myself Haskell.
I am creating a module that will process student grade records. For starters, I want it to have a function accept two lists (student names and grades) and turns it into a list of tuples [(Name, Grade)]

I have  this:

```
module StudentGrades (
    enterGrades
) where

    enterGrades :: [String] -> [Double] -> [(String,Double)]
    enterGrades [] [] = []
    enterGrades [[names]] [grades] = zip [[names]] [grades]
```

It compiles fine, but when I try running the function by typing **`enterGrades ["Ann", "Dan"] [3, 4]`**, it gives me an error:

```
*StudentGrades> enterGrades ["Ann", "Dan"] [3, 4]
*** Exception: question4.hs:(11,5)-(12,59): Non-exhaustive patterns in function enterGrades

*StudentGrades>
```

At the same time, entering **`zip ["Ann", "Dan"] [3, 4]`** in Prelude terminal works fine and returns **`[("Ann",3),("Dan",4)]`**

I don't understand why.
Please help! Thank you.

Comment: which values of type `[String]` do you think the pattern `[[names]]` applies to? Same for `[Double]` and `[grades]`?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

A single string is a list of characters, and a list of strings is , therefore, a list of lists. No?

"Same for double and [grades]" Now I am completely lost. Would you kindly explain?

Comment: Yes, a list of strings is a list of lists (of characters). I'm asking which subset of lists of strings you believe are covered by the pattern `[[names]]`, because you seem to be suffering from some sort of misunderstanding there.

Comment: As a hint, what would a pattern like `[a, b]` capture? Are there any restrictions on the length of lists that match that? Now what about `[a]`?

Comment: try `enterGrades ["a"] [1]`. did it work? -- try defining `foo [[names]] [grades] = names` and calling `foo ["a"] [1]`. What does it return?

Comment: Thank you! I changed the last line to 'enterGrades names grades = zip names grades' , and it's working now!

Haskell makes my poor head hurt :(

Comment: Would you kindly help again?

If I want to feed that list of tuples **[a]** to another function along with a single student name, so that it would fetch the student's grade, how would I do it?

So far I have this, and now I am lost as to how unpack a tuple from the incoming list of tuples:

    checkGrade :: String -> [a] -> Double
        checkGrade name (x:xs)
          | name ==

Comment: https://imgur.com/zaOzSvU

^^ Code screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Robin (and everyone else)! I changed the last line to `enterGrades names grades = zip names grades` , and it's working now!

Comment: Note that, after that change, you no longer need the first line, since `zip` will handle empty lists just fine. Indeed, `enterGrades = zip` would also work.

Comment: Why not just use `zip` in the first place? Reimplementing basic library functions on your own, to see how to define them (and prove to yourself that they're not in any sense "magic") is one thing, but that's clearly not the case here as you use `zip` in your definition anyway.